# What is the difference between Astar and Dijkstra algorithms in Pgrouting?

Tags: pgrouting

I would like to know what is the difference between A* algorithm and Dijkstra at finding the shortest path at pgrouting.

Which one is faster ,has better performance and returns better results.

Also i would like to know if it is possible for pgrouting to take into account that a road is one way when it computes the shortest path thus not traversing it

Sorry for my english 
thanks in advance john

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332466/how-does-dijkstras-algorithm-and-a-star-compare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A* is a generalised form of the Dijkstra search algorith. There are good descriptions of both on Wikipedia ([A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm), [Dijkstra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)) including nice graphical representations.

Essentially A* is faster, and will find the "best" solution given some reasonable assumptions. Dijkstra (i.e. A* without heuristic) is better conditioned. I usually choose Dijkstra until the problem space grows too large and I need something faster.

For the one-way question, just see the [documentation on this aspect of pgRouting](http://pgrouting.org/docs/howto/oneway.html).